# Is it safe to leave private information such as API keys in javascript in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api-key

I added a media button in WordPress editor, just like the code

```
add_action('media_buttons', 'add_my_media_button');
function add_my_media_button() {
    echo '
            <input id="up_to_chevereto" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"/>
            <label for="up_to_chevereto" id="up_img_label"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> upload images to Chevereto</label>
          ';
?>
<style type="text/css">...</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#up_to_chevereto').change(function() {
...
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

I left my api key in the javascript area, I wonder if this is safe or not.

Comment: did you left your API key in javscript, or in php?

Comment: And for What API is this key? Can you restrict key per domain?

Comment: I left my API key in javscript

Comment: no, the key allow the user to upload image to the image hosting based on chevereto, not for domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always insecure to leave API keys within javascript code. 
If it is unnecessary, then see on Chevereto for your API key settings to restrict usage per domain. 
If such option is not possible, then you should avoid rendering your API key in javascript.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer,  I'll try to avoid my key in javscript